Avoiding Cartan subalgebra in a Lie algebra
Let $G$ be a simple complex algebraic group acting on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ via the adjoint representation.
What is the largest integer $d$ such that every subspace $U \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ with $\dim(U) \leq d$ has trivial intersection with some Cartan subalgebra?
In other words, I am interested in the value of
$$
\max \{ d \mid \forall U \leq \mathfrak{g} \colon \; \dim(U) \leq d \Rightarrow U \cap \mathfrak{t} = 0 \text{ for some Cartan subalgebra } \mathfrak{t} \}.
$$
I am particularly interested in the case where $G = \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ acting by conjugation on $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{C})$.

My first guess would be $d$ to be the maximal possible candidate, i.e., equals the codimension of $T$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. This is obvious for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ ($d=2$) and I have a rough sketch in mind for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ ($d=6$?), but with some details to check.

Where does the intersection $U\cap T$ live if, say, $G$ is of type $G_2$?

On reflection I guess what you mean is that $U\cap {\mathfrak t} =0$ for any Cartan subalgebra ${\mathfrak t}$ of ${\mathfrak g}$.

@YCor: Yes, I think I also have an idea on how to do $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ with $d = 6$, but I do not know how to generalize this to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. I suspect the asnwer should be $n^2 - n$ in general.

@PaulLevy: Right, thanks for the correction, I have edited the question.
